# get progress of calling method

Tags: java

I need some advice.

I have a service class with a method which calls about 10 repositories methods. For example:

```
public void serviceMethod() {
    repositoryMethod1();
    repositoryMethod2();
    repositoryMethod3();
    ....
}
```

Executing of service method takes a lot of time and I need to get a current progress of it in percentage.

I can log some info after every calling of repository methods. For example.

```
public void serviceMethod() {
    repositoryMethod1();
    --log that 10% is completed
    repositoryMethod2();
    --log that 20% is completed
    ....
}
```

I think it is bad solution and I want to find the best one. Can somebody give me some advice?

I thought about AOP (advice for repository methods) but repository methods can be  called by another service and I don't know how to determine percentage.

Comment: *I think it is bad solution*: why do you think so? That looks very simple and easy to understand to me.

Comment: Why not post this on code review instead of here since its a very broad question?

Comment: @JBNizet I think it will add duplicate of code.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the most efficient solution but I have an idea. Measure the time it takes for the method to finish. Then using that value calculate percentage complete and log it to the console. Then just write a separate method performing this action.
For example if the method took 60 seconds to run you would do 100(percentage)/60(time it takes) and get 1.6(roughly) then in a separate method use java.util.timer and create a timer to tick every 1.6 seconds. on every tick just log a percent to the console and boom, your loading timer has been created.

note results might be slightly skewed because of the computer running this method along side your other method.

Comment: I thought about such solution but execution of method always different and takes about 3 hour.